# How to determine the file MIME type by content?

Tags: haskell, mime

Is there some way to determine the MIME type of a file by it's content ? Maybe with some Haskell library ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Haskell bindings to libmagic](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/magic) might be a solution to your problem. Here's an example.

```
import Magic
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main =  do
  magic <- magicOpen [MagicMime]
  (file:_) <- getArgs
  magicLoadDefault magic
  mime <- magicFile magic file
  putStrLn mime
```